# Limit of a $f_n(x)= \left(\frac{1}{1-n^2 \frac{x_0-x}{x}} \right)^{1/n} \text{ for } x \in \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1}x_0, x_0 \right]$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose we have a function defined as
$$\begin{align}
f_n(x)&= \left(\frac{1}{1-n^2 \frac{x_0-x}{x}} \right)^{1/n} \text{ for } x \in \left( \frac{n^2}{n^2+1}x_0, x_0 \right],\\
f_n(x)&=0 \text{ everywhere else }
\end{align}$$
and where $x_0>0$.

How to find this limit?
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=f(x)
\end{align}$$

Since, by assumption $x> \frac{n^2}{n^2+1}x_0$ which implies that $n^2 \frac{x_0-x}{x}<1$, so the function is always positive.

My thought is that the limit should be

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&= 1 \text{ for } x=x_0\\
f(x)&=0 \text{ everywhere else }.
\end{align}$$

Moreover, because $1 \le \frac{1}{1-n^2 \frac{x_0-x}{x}}$ this implies that
$$1 \le f(x)  \text{ at } x=x_0.$$
How to show the rest of the argument?

Answer (score 0):

First, suppose $x > x_0$, then we have $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, thus clearly $f(x) = 0$.
Now, suppose $x < x_0$, so we can write $x + \epsilon x_0= x_0$ for $\epsilon >0$.
Furthermore, we have for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $\frac{ n^2}{n^2+1} x_0 = 1 - \frac{1}{n^2+1}x_0$. So since $x = x_0 - \epsilon x_0$, we have for $n^2 \ge \epsilon^{-1} -1$ that $x_0 - \frac{1}{n^2+1}x_0 \ge x_0 - \epsilon x_0 = x$, thus $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$ such that $n^2 \ge \epsilon^{-1} -1$, and thus $f(x) =0$.
And for $x=x_0$, we have $f_n(x_0)=1$.